# Parent directory in R

Tags: r

How do I get the path to parent directory in R?
I have to write an R script that takes input from a directory in the parent directory and outputs data into another directory in the parent folder. So, if I could find path to parent folder, then I could do this.

Answer (score 49):

You can use `dirname` on `getwd` to extract everything but the top most level of your current directory:

```
dirname(getwd())
[1] "C:/Documents and Settings"
```

Answer (score 38):

Actually **dirname** allows to go back to several parent folders

```
Path="FolderA/FolderB/FolderC/FolderD"

dirname(Path)
```

"FolderA/FolderB/FolderC"

```
dirname(dirname(Path))
```

"FolderA/FolderB"

And so on...

Comment: This is exactly what I needed for a project I'm working on now, thanks!

Answer (score 29):

I assume you mean parent directory of R's working directory?

The simplest solution is probably as follows.

```
wd <- getwd()
setwd("..")
parent <- getwd()
setwd(wd)
```

This saves the working directory, changes it to its parent, gets the result in `parent`, and resets the working directory again. This saves having to deal with the vagaries of root directories, home directories, and other OS-specific features, which would probably require a bunch of fiddling with regexes.

Comment: +1 for the "..". I always use it in the terminal with cd, but I never needed into `R`, good to do. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Possibly these two tips may help

```
"~/"  # after the forward slash you "are" in your home folder
```

then on windows

```
"C:/" # you are in your main hard drive
"G:/" # you are just in another hard drive :-)
```

on unix you can do something similar with

```
"/etc/"
```

then you can go down into any sub directory you need

Or as @Hong Ooi suggests you can go up to the parent dir of your working directory with

```
"../"
```

NB: just after the final forward slash press `tab` and you'll have all the file and folder, very handy, especially in `RStudio`

Comment: @user2449961 if you mean the parent of the working directory ( you should be more precise) "../" **is** the path you need. sorry, just give a try. type literally `"../"` and after the `/` press tab and you'll see all the file inside the parent folder

Comment: @user2449961 if you delete comment then others would not make sense for new viewers of the question

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility:

```r
parts <- unlist(strsplit(getwd(), .Platform$file.sep))
do.call(file.path, as.list(parts[1:length(parts) - 1]))
```

This splits the filepath into directories, drops the last directory, and then recombines the parts into a filepath again.

Comment: this was perfect for getting the second directory in the file path, from a list of file paths that had different numbers of sub-directories (so different numbers of nested `dirname()`'s would have been necessary).

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `".."` like `output_dir <- paste(input_dir, "..", "out", sep = .Platform$file.sep)`, or using the [`fs`](https://github.com/r-lib/fs) package (`install.packages("fs")`):

```r
input_dir <- "base/input"
parent_dir <- fs::path(input_dir, "..") # "base/input/.."
output_dir <- fs::path(input_dir, "..", "out") # "base/input/../out"
# to shorten the path (avoid "input/../") you could use `fs::normalize`:
fs::normalize(fs::path(input_dir, "..", "out")) # "base/out"
# in case input is a symlink and you want the parent directory of the target, look at `fs::real`
```

Answer (score -1):

In RStudio you could navigate to your code directory and "Set As Working Directory" in Files. And then ".." will work.

[image]